# How to overlay zoom icons over images and always keep them lined up perfectly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me crazy because I *know* there's a way to do it, I just don't know how. Here's what I've come up with as a replication of the problem I'm having:

http://jsbin.com/yikuda

Play with the window width and see what happens. How can I get the plus icons to stay in the right spot, even when the images stack one per row as opposed to three per row?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="product text-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="product text-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="product text-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.zoom-btn {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 45px;
}
```

Comment: What is the right spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/vavabe/1

1. Your absolute positioned item needs a parent with position:relative.
2. Your image needs to have `.img-responsive` class on it, but it also has to be VERY big if you use `.container-fluid`. I use `.container` in this example.
3. A div surrounding an image (the element keeping the icon in position) is not the size of the image unless that div is floated or inline-block and then you need to adjust, if necessary, for that (with the img width adjustment in the max-width).
4. You don't need `.col-X-12` in most situations. Anything below the last column class used will be 100%.

[image]
[image]

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row product-row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="product text-center">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/500" class="img-responsive">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="product text-center">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/500" class="img-responsive">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="product text-center">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/500" class="img-responsive">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.product {
    position: relative
}
.zoom-btn {
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
@media (max-width:991px) { 
    .product-row {
        text-align: center
    }
    .product {
        display: inline-block;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto 10px;
    }
    .product img {
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but I don't really want to expand the images like that. Basically I've got a product page with a grid of products, and depending on the browser width, the products will space out from each other (since their contents are centered).

Comment: PS: I edited my original code and added `position: relative` to `.product`. Unfortunately it didn't fix it.

Comment: Yes, so you read #3 ... div surrounding the image is not the same size as image unless its .inline-block or floated, so you do this: https://jsbin.com/botaqo/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="product text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign zoom-btn"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just add to col-md...for what is youre preferable as long as it equals to 12.. maybe col-md-8 and col-md-4 is equl to col-md-12